# Unity 2d forwards and backwards instead of left and right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im working on a 2D ship fighting game in which you play as a battleship with sideways facing cannons. i do not want you to be able to move sideways because of this, so i want the player to only be able to move forward/backward and the A and D keys will rotate the player in their respective directions. my code has rotations working fine, even though i am aware it is probably not optimized. i tried using transform.forward but it didnt work with my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveSpeed;
    public float smoothing;

    private bool inputU;
    private bool inputD;
    private bool inputL;
    private bool inputR;
    public float rotationSpeedL;
    public float rotationSpeedR;

    private Vector2 dir;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        inputU = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W);
        inputD = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S);
        inputL = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A);
        inputR = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D);

        if (inputU && inputD || !inputU && !inputD)
        {
            dir.y = dir.y/2;
        }
        else
        {
            if (inputU)
            {
                dir.y = 1;
            }
            if (inputD)
            {
                dir.y = -1;
            }
        }
        if (inputL)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0,0,rotationSpeedL);
        }
        if (inputR)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0,0,rotationSpeedR);
        }
        if (dir.magnitude>1)
        {
            dir = dir.normalized;
        }
        rb.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(rb.velocity, dir * moveSpeed, smoothing);    
        
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use transform.up instead of transform.forward, as transform.forward doesn't really exist in 2D. Transform.forward would move the ship along the ships z axis, whereas transform.up keeps the movement relative to the "forwards" direction of the ship. You will also want to change dir to just a Vector2, with all values the same (as you might want to move the ship along the x axis, not just the y axis), so

```
if (inputU)
            {
                dir = Vector2.one;
            }
```

or just a float:

```
if (inputU)
                {
                    dir = 1;
                }
```

After implementing these changes, the code should look like this:

```
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float smoothing;

    private bool inputU;
    private bool inputD;
    private bool inputL;
    private bool inputR;
    public float rotationSpeedL;
    public float rotationSpeedR;

    private float dir;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        inputU = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W);
        inputD = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S);
        inputL = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A);
        inputR = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D);

        if (inputU && inputD || !inputU && !inputD)
        {
            dir = dir / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            if (inputU)
            {
                dir = 1;
            }
            if (inputD)
            {
                dir = -1;
            }
        }
        if (inputL)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0,0,rotationSpeedL);
        }
        if (inputR)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0,0,rotationSpeedR);
        }
        Debug.Log(transform.forward);
        rb.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(rb.velocity, dir * moveSpeed * transform.up, smoothing);    
        
}
```